# Iterate with column name

Tags: r

My data frame is `result`.

It has the format like,

```
org_A      X       Y          Z
 130      44       55        66
 312      33       62        77
 ..       ..       ..        ..
```

I want to use wilcox.test to compare org_A and X, and org_A and Y, then finally org_A and Z, and print its p-value.

so the result will look like

```
X: 0.001932
Y: 0.18271
Z: 0.001231
```

For that, I implemented like this,

```
for (i in 1:ncol(result)){
colnm <- colnames(result)[i]
wilcox.test(result$org_A, result$colnm, alternative=c("two.sided"), paired=FALSE)$p.value
```

}

but it warns with message `Unknown column 'colnm'`.

Even worse, it prints something but p values are same.

What should I do?

Comment: Try `result[colnm]`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
result <- data.frame(org_A = c(130, 312, 123), 
                 x = c(44, 33, 12), 
                 y = c(55, 62, 43), 
                 z = c(66, 77, 55))

answer <- rep(NA, (ncol(result) - 1))

for (i in 2:ncol(result)) {
      answer[i-1] <- wilcox.test(result$org_A, 
                                 result[, i], 
                                 alternative = c("two.sided"),
                                 paired = FALSE)$p.value
}

answer
[1] 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

*edit*

Here's another way of using `sapply`.

```
sapply(result[, -1], FUN = function(x, result) {
  wilcox.test(result$org_A, 
              x, 
              alternative = c("two.sided"),
              paired = FALSE)$p.value
}, result = result)
```